# Macro insert and change picture in header all sheets excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am not a professional, but I am trying to find a way where a user of an excel workbook I created can select and insert a picture (company logo) in left header of all sheets in an excel workbook.
If possible it should be possible to change the picture also, i.e., remove the current picture (if any) and insert a new one. I have searched and found some solutions using macro, but have not found a complete solution to what I am trying to achieve. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work properly (with a virtual printer

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub setLeftHeaderImage()
    Const TITLE     As String = "Select Header Image"
    Const IMG_TYPES As String = "All Files (*.*),*.*,Jpg (*.jpg),*.jpg,Png (*.png),*.png"

    Dim selectedFile As Variant, iniName As String, ws As Worksheet

    selectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=IMG_TYPES, TITLE:=TITLE)
    If selectedFile <> False Then
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            With ws.PageSetup
                Application.PrintCommunication = False
                With .LeftHeaderPicture
                    .Filename = selectedFile
                    .Height = 71.25
                    .Width = 117.75
                    .Brightness = 0.36
                    .ColorType = msoPictureAutomatic     'msoPictureWatermark
                End With
                Application.PrintCommunication = True
                On Error GoTo ShowError    'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291298
                .LeftHeader = "&G"         '"&G" Enable the image to show up in left header
                .Zoom = 100
                .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
                .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
            End With
        Next
        Exit Sub
ShowError:
        MsgBox "Setup a printer and 'Print Spooler' service; (" & Err.Description & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Thanks for the suggestions EEM!

Comment: The way it's written now the code is always showing the Error Message, suggest to moved it to the end of the procedure i.e. `Exit Sub`   `ShowError:`   `MsgBox "Setup a printer and Print Spooler service; (" & Err.Description & ")"`

Comment: Thanks @EEM - I updated it (still can't test it properly)

Comment: Hi, I have copied the updated text to a new module in my excel workbook, and then run the macro. It start by a new window to select image. I select the image (logo) I want and click ok. But when I check the left header on each sheet, it's empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is without a printer. Try recording a macro while you add the logo, inspect the code generated by Excel for you, and make changes to this code to fix the issue(s). If you can fix it please provide your working code in a new answer, as a reference for others

Comment: The code is updating the header for the `activesheet` only, to have it for all sheets you need to loop through all worksheet i.e. `for ... next`

Comment: Paul a print preview will show the results, set a virtual printer as default i.e. Adobe PDF, Microsoft XPS, etc

Comment: @EEM - thanks again! Print preview seems to work now with Microsoft XPS, even though I tried it yesterday and was getting errors. But I also added the loop - you've been of great help!

Comment: Thanks paul bica and EEM for helping me. I got what I wanted. Have tried the code (with some minor modifications) and it is doing exactly what I was hoping for. THANKS!!!!!